# Question on maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

We are given domain $\Omega=\{x\in R^n:|x|>1\}$ and let $u \in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\overline \Omega)$ satisfy $\bigtriangleup u=0, \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega$. $$$$
Assume $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}|u(x)|=0$. (1)$$$$
Prove that $\sup_{\Omega}|u|=\max_{|x|=1}|u|$ $$$$
Is assumption (1) necessary? Construct a counterexample in $R^{2}$.

The mean value theorem implies that the maximum cannot occur in the interior of the boundary and assumption 1 implies that the maximum must be attained.

Any help solving this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What else do you need to prove? You know already that maximum is attained, and it is not attained in the interior....

Comment: we need to prove the sup|u|=max|x|=1 |u| and give a counterexample of a harmonic fn in omega that doesnt achieve a max at the boundary.

Comment: What is stopping you to show that $\sup |u| =\max _{|x|=1}|u|$?